# DirectX Version information

Tags: directx, version

I need to get the version information of the DirectX installed in my machine(major and minor version information). I tried using the DirectXSetupGetVersion API, but this was returning 4.09.00.0904 for my machine which was installed with DirectX 11. This value is wrong according to the following Wiki Link : http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DirectX. Can anyone help me in finding the exact version information for the DirectX.

Regards,
Midhun

Answer (score 0):

You should explain *why* you want to know the "DirectX Version".

Unless you are dealing with ancient versions of Windows (i.e. Windows 9x / ME), the main way to know what DirectX is available is based on the OS version. This is best done as a "you must be this high to ride this ride" style check. I cover how to do this in [this blog post](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/chuckw/archive/2010/02/24/what-s-in-a-version-number.aspx) which should be done in an installer and not by an application.

For Direct3D 11 there's some complexity here if you want to support Windows Vista. This is covered in great detail by the [Direct3D 11 Deployment for Game Developers](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ee416644.aspx) article and [Direct3D 11 Install Helper](https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/Direct3D-11-Install-Helper-3044575e) sample.

Once the application starts, the best way to determine if a particular version is available is to try to create the device and/or QueryInterface the version. For a Direct3D 11 minimum app, I cover this in [Anatomy of Direct3D 11 Create Device](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/chuckw/archive/2014/02/05/anatomy-of-direct3d-11-create-device.aspx).

If you are concerned about not having Direct3D 11--like on Windows XP because you've set your 'you must be this high to ride this ride' check that low--, you'd use explicit rather than implicit loading to get the entry point to create that Direct3D 11 device.

```
static PFN_D3D11_CREATE_DEVICE s_DynamicD3D11CreateDevice = nullptr;

if ( !s_DynamicD3D11CreateDevice )
{            
    HMODULE hModD3D11 = LoadLibrary( L"d3d11.dll" );
    if ( !hModD3D11 )
        // error 

    s_DynamicD3D11CreateDevice = reinterpret_cast<PFN_D3D11_CREATE_DEVICE>( GetProcAddress( hModD3D11, "D3D11CreateDevice" ) ); 
    if ( !s_DynamicD3D11CreateDevice )
       // error, no Direct3D 11 present on the system
}

HRESULT hr = s_DynamicD3D11CreateDevice( ... );
if ( FAILED(hr) )
    // error
```

The other thing to remember is that the "DirectX version" has absolutely **nothing at all** to do with what the *DirectX End-User Runtime* (aka DirectSetup, DXSETUP, DXWSETUP) actually does on Windows starting with Windows XP Service Pack 2. See [No So Direct Setup](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/chuckw/archive/2010/09/08/not-so-direct-setup.aspx). If you need to check for D3DX, XAudio2.7, XACT, XInput 1.3, Managed DirectX 1.1, etc. you have to explicitly load the right DLL.